# Physics of swimming

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I understand that pushing water backwards due to resistance we propel forward. But how moving our legs propel us ? also how dolphins can move moving up and down their tail ? isnt the reactive that they exert backwards ?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this question has been asked before, but the first answer that comes to my mind is to remember to treat the force of your legs as in vector terms.

In other words, unless your legs (and the dolphin's tail) travel in a totally vertical plane, which they don't, there will always be a force pushing you forward.

In the dolphin's case, the curvature and flexibility of its tail assures this, any slow motion movie of a dolphin swimming will show it clearly.

Comment: Correct, their tails are essentially "wings" that generate a forward directed "lift" force on both the up and the downstroke.

Comment: @JMLCarter, I agree.  A careful viewing of a movie of a dolphin swimming clearly shows vortices that are produced by its tail as it swims.  This is very reminiscent of the vortices coming off of airliner wingtips.